# Beginner Django: How to order a queryset by a property

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have a model:

```py
class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField("Project title", max_length=128)
    start_date = models.DateField("Project start date", blank=True, null=True)
    end_date = models.DateField("Project end date", blank=True, null=True)

    @property
    def has_ended(self):
        return self.end_date is not None and self.end_date < timezone.now().date()
```

And I want to order projects by two fields: start_date (desc) and also show projects that have not ended first. I know I can't ordery by a property, so I tried the following solution:

```py
class ProjectViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Project.objects.all().order_by("-start_date")
    queryset = sorted(queryset, key=lambda a: a.has_ended)
    serializer_class = ProjectSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
```

which is the one that has already been answered on other posts with this question. However, I still get the following error:

`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'model'`

I also tried using Django annotations like this:

```py
    queryset = Project.objects.annotate(has_ended=F('start_date')-F('end_date')).order_by('has_ended', '-start_date')
```

But server returns this error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 78, in __iter__
django_1  |     setattr(obj, attr_name, row[col_pos])
django_1  | AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

I ran out of ideas on how to achieve the behavior I want. Can someone please give me a hand on that?

Answer (score 0):

Here you are changing `queryset` attribute to a `list` instance:

```py
queryset = sorted(queryset, key=lambda a: a.has_ended)
```

You cannot do that, because the view needs proper `QuerySet` object.

You can use simple filter that clean Django `QuerySet` can evaluate:

```py
queryset = Project.objects.filter(end_date__lt=timezone.now().date()).order_by("-start_date")
```

The expression `lt` means `less than`. Double underscore is separating parts of the logic chain which you are filtering by.

Comment: But that query removes ended projects from the query results. I just want them to be the last ones to show.

Comment: @GuillermoLupiáñezTapia oh, can't you just sort by end date?

Comment: You are completely right, I don't know how I didn't think that second requirement was just a clarification for the first one. Thanks a lot!!